# Exception when testing custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

We get serialized DateTimes from an API in a strange format like this: `/Date(1574487012797)/`
To deserialize this value with `System.Text.Json`, we wrote our own `JsonConverter`:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var dateTimeString = reader.GetString();
        dateTimeString = dateTimeString.Replace("/Date(", "");
        dateTimeString = dateTimeString.Replace(")/", "");
        var epoch = Convert.ToInt64(dateTimeString);
        var dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(epoch);
        return dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ"));
    }
}
```

I'd like to write a Unit Test for this converter.
What I tried is the following:

```
public class DateTimeConverterTest
{
    private readonly DateTimeConverter testee;

    public DateTimeConverterTest()
    {
        this.testee = new DateTimeConverter();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Read_WhenCalledWithSerializedDateTime_ThenReturnDeserializedDateTime()
    {
        var a = "{\r\n \"PublikationsDatum\": \"/Date(1573581177000)/\" \r\n}";
        //var serializedDateTime = "/Date(1573581177000)/";
        var utf8JsonReader = new Utf8JsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a), false, new JsonReaderState(new JsonReaderOptions()));
        //utf8JsonReader.TokenType = JsonTokenType.String;
        var deserializedDateTime = this.testee.Read(ref utf8JsonReader, typeof(DateTime), new JsonSerializerOptions {IgnoreNullValues = true});

    }

    private class TestClass
    {
        public DateTime PublikationsDatum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when trying to execute the Unit Test, I get an `InvalidOperationException` at `var dateTimeString = reader.GetString();`

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot get the value of a token type 'None' as a string.'

How can I setup the test correctly / what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before you can call [`JsonConverter<T>.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.read?view=netcore-3.0#System_Text_Json_Serialization_JsonConverter_1_Read_System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader__System_Type_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) you must advance the [`Utf8JsonReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader?view=netcore-3.0) until it is positioned on the value of the `"PublikationsDatum"` property, e.g. like so:

```
public void Read_WhenCalledWithSerializedDateTime_ThenReturnDeserializedDateTime()
{
    var a = "{\r\n \"PublikationsDatum\": \"/Date(1573581177000)/\" \r\n}";
    var utf8JsonReader = new Utf8JsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a), false, new JsonReaderState(new JsonReaderOptions()));
    while (utf8JsonReader.Read())
        if (utf8JsonReader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
            break;
    var deserializedDateTime = this.testee.Read(ref utf8JsonReader, typeof(DateTime), new JsonSerializerOptions {IgnoreNullValues = true});
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/05vmqC).

Alternatively, you could simplify your unit test by parsing a simple JSON string literal `"/Date(1573581177000)/"`.  However, you will still need to advance the reader once because it is initially positioned before the beginning of the first token, with `utf8JsonReader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.None`:

```
public void Read_WhenCalledWithSerializedDateTime_ThenReturnDeserializedDateTime()
{
    var a = "\"/Date(1573581177000)/\"";
    var utf8JsonReader = new Utf8JsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a), false, new JsonReaderState(new JsonReaderOptions()));
    // Reader always starts out without having read anything yet, so TokenType == JsonTokenType.None initially
    Assert.IsTrue(utf8JsonReader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.None);
    utf8JsonReader.Read();
    var deserializedDateTime = this.testee.Read(ref utf8JsonReader, typeof(DateTime), new JsonSerializerOptions {IgnoreNullValues = true});
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fLtQVw).

Notes:

- `"\/Date(number of ticks)\/"` is the format used by Microsoft's original `JavaScriptSerializer` for serializing a `DateTime` to a JSON string.  See [the documentation remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) for details.

  (Within a JSON [string literal](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7), `\/` is just an escaped `\` and will be silently interpreted as such by `Utf8JsonReader`, see fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HSAzpU).  You don't need to check for `\/` within your JSON converter to handle `JavaScriptSerializer` generated dates and times.)
- `DataContractSerializer` used a slightly different format.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/stand-alone-json-serialization#datetime-wire-format):

  > DateTime values appear as JSON strings in the form of "/Date(700000+0500)/", where the first number (700000 in the example provided) is the number of milliseconds in the GMT time zone, regular (non-daylight savings) time since midnight, January 1, 1970. The number may be negative to represent earlier times. The part that consists of "+0500" in the example is optional and indicates that the time is of the Local kind - that is, should be converted to the local time zone on deserialization. If it is absent, the time is deserialized as Utc. The actual number ("0500" in this example) and its sign (+ or -) are ignored.
- Newtonsoft's implementation of [`DateTimeUtils.TryParseDateTimeMicrosoft()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/DateTimeUtils.cs#L522) may be helpful in guiding your implementation.

Comment: Awesome answer! I had the _exact_ same question (and similar code) as the OP - so this is such great timing and help. Well done!