# DateTime format in System.Text.Json migrating from JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json.net, datetime-format, system.text.json, javascriptserializer

I'm trying to migrate from `JavaScriptSerializer` to `System.Text.Json` and I see that the latter doesn't understand serialized data from the former. `Newtonsoft` understands the format but I need `System.Text.Json`. How can I workaround it? What other snags can I hit?

```
var str = "{ \"Date\": \"\\/Date(1471463788903)\\/\" }";
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<D>(str);
var newntonsoft = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<D>(str);
var system = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<D>(str); // throws

public class D { public DateTime Date { get; set; } }
```

Comment: The format you are seeing is called [Microsoft DateTime wire format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/stand-alone-json-serialization#datetime-wire-format) and is indeed different from the ISO formats you are used to seeing. In this [issue here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30776) a (ex-) Microsoft employee states that they made a conscious decision to not support this format in `System.Text.Json`. There are however [custom converters available](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Macross.Json.Extensions/) that do support the Microsoft date format.

Comment: @nbokmans alas, I'm not allowed to use third-party packages.

Comment: So then you could take a look at the source code of the package, maybe a specific look at the MicrosoftDateTime Converter, see how they implement it, and implement it yourself in your code base? It comes down to needing a custom converter for this data format, which `System.Text.Json` allows you to write yourself.

Comment: `I'm not allowed to use third-party packages` hallmark of an insane employer.

Comment: If you are *not allowed to use third-party packages.* then there is a converter in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58996878/3744182) by Palle Due to [Deserializing JSON to DateTime property throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58995639/3744182) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59028159/3744182) by xeraphim.

Comment: @IanKemp yeah, but then again [yanking a JS leftpad routine from npm broke the internet](https://www.theregister.com/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/)

Comment: @HasBeanCounter If you're working in a corporate environment and don't have a local cache of the packages your org uses, you deserve whatever pain you get.